# How to import 3D scene (.obj file with .mtl file)

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, fbx

I bought a 3D Model of a room. The model is in the `.obj` format. Now, I'm trying to import this model into Unity3D.

The Model came with:

- `5` x `.obj` files
- `5` x `.mtl` files
- `n` x `.jpg` files
- `n` x `.tga` files

The `.mtl` files contained paths that do not exist on my PC. So I removed the paths. The images files (`.jpg` & `.mtl`) are in the same directory as the `.obj` files. When I tried to import the `.obj` files, the room has no material on it. 
I then tried to use the FBX converter (with "Embed media" checked) to convert the `.obj` to `.fbx` and still when I import it, there is no material on the 3D room (it's invisible). I also tried importing all the `.jpg` and `.tga` files to a folder underneath the root Assets folder in Unity then importing the `.obj` and `.mtl` files.

What am I doing wrong? Does Unity3D use the `.mtl` to determine where to find the image files required? Is there an import log that could possibly shed some light?

---

#### UPDATE [8/25/2015]

1. I edited all my `.mtl` files and removed the paths so its just the image filename (i.e. `map_Ka Arch 53-wood 14.jpg`).
2. I copied all my `.jpg` and `.tga` files to a *"Textures"* folder in the same directory.
3. I used the FBX Converter to convert the `.obj` files to `.fbx`.
4. Imported the `.fbx` into Unity3D.

It still creates a model with no material (invisible) on it but the material folder it automatically creates upon import has much less files in it and those files map to images I imported under my Assets folder -- maybe this is progress? Not sure...

#### UPDATE [8/25/2015] #2

Possibly my model is importing correctly but I'm not setting something right? My `.fbx` model that I imported has number of Mesh filters underneath it. Each Mesh filter's Albedo does map to an image that I imported underneath my Assets folder (see screen shot) but still still when I drag the root model into my scene it is transparent -- why?

#### UPDATE [8/27/2015]

I was not able to get the `.obj` / `.mtl` combo working. I was able to get the author to convert to fbx so I'm trying to get that working as well (same issues I'm having with my converted fbx files). I create a new SO question at this point ([Imported .fbx model Is Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259456/imported-fbx-model-is-transparent))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you make progress afterwards? I am facing the same situation at the moment. Any help will be great!

Comment: My model was way out in space ....meaning after I zoomed out I could see it ....then I dragged it back down to where all the rest of my objects were.

Comment: Yeah eventually I also converted everything to fbx along with all the texture images in the same folder and it worked. Thanks though :>

Answer (score 3):

- use fbx (convert obj to fbx, obj doesn't work)
- import fbx as asset
- import textrure images files as asset
  (image naming: modelname_Texture_0.jpg modelname_Texture_1.jpg etc, fbx name: modelname.fbx)
- select the model from favorites -> all models
  in the inspectors tab under materials
- select import materials > 
  material naming
- select model name + model's material
  material search
- select local material's folder
- click apply
  done

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and correct) way to do this will be to not use the .mtl file. Rather just bring in the textures and models, then create a material inside Unity. As a starting point it would probably be best to use the Standard shader. And then just drag the textures to the right properties on the material.

There is a small chance that the above won't work if the UV's are not correct in the mesh, but there is a very good chance that it *will* work.

You didn't mention the names of the textures, but presumably they will roughly match up with the property names.
For instance, `_d`_ may be the `Diffuse`/`Albedo`.

EDIT: In the case where the above isn't an option (like your complicated object), you may have success by using the `Import Materials`, `Material Naming` and `Material Search` options in the import settings of the model. However, that assumes that at least the texture references are withing the .obj, which may not be the case.

Comment: I tried just importing the .obj file --- it imports it with many many objects underneath it plus a materials folder with again many object in it (see screen shot) . I'm not sure what to drag where.

Comment: Made an edit above which may help. You mentioned that you tried an FBX converter. You could try putting it into blender, and exporting from there with embedded media.

Comment: Hmmm yea maybe importing the obj or  fbx file into blender.  Also see my update above "UPDATE [8/25/2015]"

Comment: Tried importing obj and fbx files into Blender , neither works ---- no errors or messages  ---nothing happens actually --- so not sure what went wrong .