# Imported .fbx model Is Transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, autodesk, fbx

My model seems importing correctly but maybe I'm not setting something right? My fbx model that I imported has number of Mesh filters underneath it . Each Mesh filter's Albedo does map to an image that I imported underneath my Assets folder (see screen shot) but still when I drag the root model into my scene it is transparent ---why?

[image]

---

#### UPDATE: 09-01-2015

I had the 3d model author tick "embed media" when exporting from Autodesk. Now the import adds  a .fbm folder in my Assets. The .fbm folder contains the images and there is a populated "Materials" folder added as well. But still when I drag the model on to the stage, it is transparent---what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the model was dragged onto the scene, and although its position of `(x, y, z)` was `(0, 0, 0)`, the model was nowhere to be be seen. My *existing* objects were at `(0, 0, 0)` and right in view in the scene. So I assumed my model was transparent or imported incorrectly somehow.

This issue really was my model was waaaay out in the distance -- it looked like a spec from the `(0, 0, 0)` coordinates of my existing models. I dragged it back to where my other objects are and then I could see it clearly. Not sure why it defaulted to way out there, even when its position was located at `(0, 0, 0)`.