# Can't apply materials in unity from .mtl file

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have imported a fbx file with all the textures and materials but .mtl file can't seems to be read by unity I have tried extract textures form the folder but it doesn't help either [image]

Comment: Have you tried manually dragging the according image texture onto the according materials "Albedo" slot?

Comment: @derHugo yes i'm doing it this way but there must be a proper solution for this?

Comment: wait btw .. `.MTL` belongs to the `.OBJ` format ... in `.FBX` should already contain the texture information itself .... where do you get this OBJ from? Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211612/how-to-import-3d-scene-obj-file-with-mtl-file